# Order of logical AND operands and impact on dependencies

Tags: frama-c

I came across a strange behavior of Frama-C and have a question about it.
More precisely, it is about dependencies that come from expressions with the logical AND (&&).

The following minimal example is concerned:

```
typedef unsigned char boolean;

const boolean a = 0;
extern boolean b;
extern boolean res;

void main(){
    res = a && b;
}
```

My expectation here is that the value of res depends only on the value of a, because the value of res will be 0 regardless of the value of b (as long as a is 0). This also matches the dependency list.

```
[from] ====== DEPENDENCIES COMPUTED ======
  These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:
[from] Function main:
  res FROM a
[from] ====== END OF DEPENDENCIES ======
```

It becomes more interesting if the order of a and b is reversed.

```
res = b && a;
```

Also for this example I would expect the same dependencies as before. But these have also changed due to the change of order.

```
 res FROM a; b
```

I think this can be traced back to short-circuit evaluation (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical). In the first case, only the lhs is evaluated, in the second case lhs and rhs are evaluated. This is where the difference in the dependency lists comes from.

**Now my question:**

Is there a way to get the expected dependencies (res only depends on a) in both cases without explicitly changing the order?
My first approach was a conditional assignment through:

```
res = !a ? (a && b) : (b && a);
```

However, this also presupposes the adaptation of all the corresponding lines of code. Is there an easier way (possibly a Frama-C option I overlooked)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why do you think `b` is unitialized? It is defined in another module, and as a global variable is at least zero-initialized.

Comment: You want `res` to only depends on `a`, whatever the value of a is ?

Comment: @qdesmettre no. But as long as a is 0 I want res only depend on a.

Comment: Does the complementary case with `a = 1` and `a && b` / `b && a` produce similar effects? I'm afraid you want too much from the analyzer. Lazy evaluation can be used by purpose, and you want to invert the logic.

Comment: To get the same result with a = 1 the logical AND must be replaced by a logical OR. But yes, in this case (with a = 1 and res = a || b / res = b || a) you get the same result.

Comment: I don't think it's currently possible. You could try `-constfold`, for instance, but it would produce the opposite result: either `res FROM b` (`b && a`) or `res FROM \nothing` (`a && b`). In theory it might be possible to improve the results of From by using values inferred from Eva, but it would probably require tighter coupling between the plugins (which is intended to happen someday). If alternative semantics interest you, you could even try the undocumented (and experimental) option `-keep-logical-operators`, which combined with `-constfold` results in `res FROM \nothing` in both cases.

Comment: Thank you @anol. I have tested both options. But as you already indicated, this does not eliminate the dependency on b.